# Rails - best practice to store dictionaries (key value pairs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

I need some architectural advice. I'm more into java, but trying to get up to speed with Ruby-on-rails. In the app I am building I need a convenient place to store some dictionary values that will be later used in various places of the application. These will be usually key value pairs - e.g. list of values to be used in select list.

The main objective is to keep this logic in one place of the application.

I am considering following options:

1. Store values in the database - i'm kind of reluctant from that, as values won't change very often.
2. Put all of the values in one class. In JAVA I'd have some static properties in one class holding this values (e.g. call Utils.getStates() will return list of states). How to do it ruby way?
3. Have some .yml file with values - read from the values. How to do it? I guess I have to parse the file in the initializer, but is there any tutorial how to do it?

Precise example? Let's say that have a model that have a field called "Type". Type can be: `['Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'...]`. And of course, for each type I want to have key and value.

I'd appreciate some suggestions about how you solve this problem in your apps.

Thanks,
Maciek

Answer (score 3):

How often does the list change? Is it acceptable to have developers involved each time a value changes (updating code, re-deploying the app)? If the answer is *no* then store the values in a database.

Is the list of values reuseable? Then a `gem` or a `yaml` file with an initializer might be a good choice.

Is it just a small list and does not change often? Then you might want to consider a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Rails any data that would change at runtime and needs to be persisted, would normally be stored in the database.  I think that would be the "rails way".  You could save the data to yaml or json file, but that would not follow the normal flow of the MVC pattern that is so common in rails